# Is it correct to explain a word using a phrase between two commas?

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses

In the following sentence I placed "gases ejected from an engine as waste products" between commas to explain what exhaust fumes is?

> Curbing exhaust fumes, **gases ejected from an engine as waste products**,
> is only the first baby step towards climate change mitigation.

Is it correct and clear? Actually I tried to reduce the following clause:

> Curbing exhaust fumes, **which are gases ejected from an engine as waste products**,
> is only the first baby step towards climate change mitigation.

Comment: Both sentences are correct. The first being an appositive phrase describing fumes and the second being an adjective clause also describing fumes. As a native American speaker, both are clear and understandable. In the second sentence, though, you would not need the commas around your clause.

Comment: @BreWoodsy I'd say (as ESL) that you'd still need commas in the second sentence. "Curbing exhaust fumes which are gases..." sounds like the speaker is specifying *which kind* of fumes should be curbed, rather than *what fumes are*. (cf. "The lawn which is green is mine." (there are two lawns, and the green one is the one that belongs to me) / "The lawn, which is green, is mine" (there's one lawn, it's green, and it belongs to me)).

Comment: @MaciejStachowski Looking over the sentence, I think you would be right. Not only for the reason that you mentioned but also because it could be considered as a nonessential element. Thanks!